# Mamp Pro cannot use SSL anymore

Tags: ssl, https, mamp, mamp-pro

I am using Mamp Pro 5 and last week I can set up and using SSL by generated a self-signed certificate.

But today when I am trying to start server again, it is doesn't work anymore. I checked on log files and it said : [Sat Oct 12 13:36:58 2019] [error] (1)Operation not permitted: Init: Can't open server certificate file (path to file)/uf.o.crt

Please let me know how to fix this.

Thanks

[This is a screenshot of error log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnszg.png)

Comment: I am facing same issue and it started happening when mac os is upgraded to catalina

Comment: @Sam  Try Seyed's solution or just uninstall your Mamp  and install it again. It should be work.

Answer (score 25):

Move the SSL certificates into the default MAMP certificates folder:

`/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs/`

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I did not try it yet because I uninstall Mamp and install it again then it's work for me.

Comment: This works. Apache is starting now but I get a `403 forbidden` on every site with ssl now: `Operation not permitted: Init: Can't open server certificate`

Comment: Thank you, this works. For anyone using WordPress and MAMP, make sure you also change your `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in wp-config.php to use **https** and port **8890**. I also change these in phpMyAdmin manually—if not, some plug-ins fail. Then login to your WP Admin area and run a plugin like [Velvet Blues](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) to update all the URLs in your database. If you don't do this, you may get weird behavior, css not loading and plug-ins breaking. Use the option `Update ALL GUIDs`.

Answer (score 8):

I have experienced the same problem after upgrading MacOS 10.15 Catalina to build 19A602 (security updates from yesterday). I used to store self created SSL Certs in my user folder and apache could not be started any more.

After moving all .crt and .key files into the folder where MAMP itself stores it's automatically generated certificates (which is `/Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs`) the problem was gone.

Of course you will have to check every single host and re-link certificate files (marked with a red exclamation mark) to make it work - but *no need to completely uninstall MAMP*

Answer (score 3):

Usually this problem appears after upgrading MacOS.

1. Disable Apache
2. Disable SSL in MAMP
3. Start Apache
4. Disable Apache
5. Enable SSL in MAMP and generate new SSL certificate
6. Start Apache

It works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I just solved it by myself and I also got this solutions from developers after I solved it.

What I did is just **full uninstall Mamp and try to install it again**.

That's all fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and solved this by moving my all projects under my home folder. SSL certificates were regenerated  (I use MAMP Pro and prefer to keep ssl certs under my projects for development purpose)

Answer (score 0):

With MAMP PRO 6, certificates are managed by MAMP. I had a problem with a certificate that was expired. I simply deleted the host and recreated the host afterwards. MAMP has generated new certificates and everything is ok.